# How can I recreate my Show Desktop icon on WinXP?

Tags: windows-xp

Quick Launch became corrupted and I need to recreate everything.  I know I've done it before but I can't remember the object name: how do I recreate the Show Desktop icon?

Comment: Should move to http://superuser.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to **`C:\Documents and settings\YourUserName\Application Data\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch`** and create a new text file; put the following inside:

```
[Shell]
Command=2
IconFile=explorer.exe,3
[Taskbar]
Command=ToggleDesktop
```

Save the file as **"Show Desktop.scf"** and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

google is your friend.

http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=how+to+recreate+the+show+desktop+icon&aq=f&oq=&aqi=g1

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190355

Answer (score 0):

From: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190355

follow these instructions:

To re-create the Show desktop icon yourself, follow these steps:

1. Click Start, click Run, type notepad
   in the Open box, and then click OK.
2. Carefully copy and then paste the
   following text into the Notepad
   window: 
   [Shell] 
   Command=2
   IconFile=explorer.exe,3 
   [Taskbar]
   Command=ToggleDesktop
3. On the File menu, click Save As, and then save  the file to your desktop as "Show    desktop.scf". The Show desktop icon is created on your desktop.
4. Click and then drag the Show desktop icon  to your Quick Launch toolbar.